# Populating multiple fields from object when one is selected

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

New to Angular.js. I have a function that that gets data and puts them into objects:

```
$scope.ContractComboBoxOptions = function (entyId, fieldId, value, contractIndex, searchOptionsName) {
    entityService.searchComboBoxItems(entyId, fieldId, value)
        //result below needs to have an array with results 
        .then(function (result) {
            var endItems = [];
            var icountr = 0;
            var test = result.updatedAddContract[0];
            angular.forEach(result, function (attr) {
                test = result.updatedAddContract[icountr];
                endItems.push(test);
                icountr++;
            });
            //$scope[searchOptionsName] = endItems;
            $scope.contracts[contractIndex][searchOptionsName] = endItems;
        });
    };
```

If I mouse over endItems you can see them:

[image]

I am trying to set 2 columns when one is picked. When I select the 1st column the data is coming in fine:

[image]

But it does not populate the next field with one of the objects like I want it too.

```
                    <tbody data-ng-repeat="(contractIndex, contract) in contracts">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="dropdown" style="width:100%">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-ng-disabled="formReadOnly" data-ng-model="contract.CONTRACT_NUM_VAL" data-ng-keyup="ContractComboBoxOptions(14, 413, contract.CONTRACT_NUM_VAL, contractIndex, 'searchContractOptions')" />
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu small" style="width:100%">
                                        <li data-ng-repeat="name in contract.searchContractOptions" style="width:100%"><a data-ng-click="changeContractData(contractIndex, 'CONTRACT_NUM_VAL', name.name)">{{name.name}}</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td><input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" data-ng-model="contract.ITEM_ID" />{{name.ITEM_ID}}</td>
                    </tbody>
```

How can I get another field to populate with the object coming in when the 1st is selected?

Edit: resulting json:

```
[{"ITEM_ID":2,"name":"10/29/2016","PROGRAM_ID":"4"},{"ITEM_ID":2,"name":"10/31/2016","PROGRAM_ID":"4"},{"ITEM_ID":2,"name":"111111111","PROGRAM_ID":"4"},{"ITEM_ID":2,"name":"A180","PROGRAM_ID":"4"},{"ITEM_ID":3,"name":"01/29/2017","PROGRAM_ID":"1"},{"ITEM_ID":3,"name":"01/31/2017","PROGRAM_ID":"1"},{"ITEM_ID":3,"name":"1","PROGRAM_ID":"1"},{"ITEM_ID":6,"name":"02/01/2017","PROGRAM_ID":"3"},{"ITEM_ID":6,"name":"02/22/2017","PROGRAM_ID":"3"},{"ITEM_ID":6,"name":"123456","PROGRAM_ID":"3"},{"ITEM_ID":6,"name":"M150","PROGRAM_ID":"3"},{"ITEM_ID":7,"name":"02/27/2017","PROGRAM_ID":"4"},{"ITEM_ID":7,"name":"02/28/2017","PROGRAM_ID":"4"},{"ITEM_ID":7,"name":"112123123123","PROGRAM_ID":"4"},{"ITEM_ID":7,"name":"A910","PROGRAM_ID":"4"}]
```

$Scope.contracts json:

```
[{"GM_FLAG":"N","COMBO_FLAG":"N","RX_MED_FLAG":"N","IV_MED_FLAG":"N","INCENTIVE_FLAG":"N","NDC_ID":-1,"searchContractOptions":[{"ITEM_ID":2,"name":"10/29/2016","PROGRAM_ID":"4"},{"ITEM_ID":2,"name":"10/31/2016","PROGRAM_ID":"4"},{"ITEM_ID":2,"name":"111111111","PROGRAM_ID":"4"},{"ITEM_ID":2,"name":"A180","PROGRAM_ID":"4"},{"ITEM_ID":3,"name":"01/29/2017","PROGRAM_ID":"1"},{"ITEM_ID":3,"name":"01/31/2017","PROGRAM_ID":"1"},{"ITEM_ID":3,"name":"1","PROGRAM_ID":"1"},{"ITEM_ID":6,"name":"02/01/2017","PROGRAM_ID":"3"},{"ITEM_ID":6,"name":"02/22/2017","PROGRAM_ID":"3"},{"ITEM_ID":6,"name":"123456","PROGRAM_ID":"3"},{"ITEM_ID":6,"name":"M150","PROGRAM_ID":"3"},{"ITEM_ID":7,"name":"02/27/2017","PROGRAM_ID":"4"},{"ITEM_ID":7,"name":"02/28/2017","PROGRAM_ID":"4"},{"ITEM_ID":7,"name":"112123123123","PROGRAM_ID":"4"},{"ITEM_ID":7,"name":"A910","PROGRAM_ID":"4"}],"$$hashKey":"00O","CONTRACT_NUM_VAL":"1"}]
```

Comment: try using deep copy.`$scope.contracts[contractIndex][searchOptionsName] = angular.copy(endItems)`

Comment: @sachilaranawaka Same behavior as before.

Comment: after assign value to this console.log this `$scope.contracts[contractIndex][searchOptionsName]` in next line. whats the result

Comment: @sachilaranawaka It prints an array of objects, the ones I want passed in.

Comment: can you post that json

Comment: @sachilaranawaka I posted the json above.

Comment: is this `contracts` or `searchOptionsName` array. if it's `searchOptionsName` can u please post the full `contracts` array also

Comment: @sachilaranawaka Is it the output of this as json: $scope.contracts[contractIndex][searchOptionsName]

Comment: no just `$scope.contracts` array

Comment: @sachilaranawaka I have added it above.

Comment: i created a plnkr and data seems to binding https://plnkr.co/edit/GHGpNIf4q3bZW5Iktq9M?p=preview